# advice on memory purchase for AMD 6134 2P server

Tags: vmware-esx, memory, 64-bit, opteron

HP DL165G7 with 2x AMD 6134 CPU.

target RAM: 48GB
options:

1. 2GB dual rank registered DIMM  - 24 Qty HP-2GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600R-9 Kit
2. 4Gb single rank registered DIMM - 12 Qty HP-4GB 1Rx4 PC3-10600R-9 Kit

which of the above is recommended for performance (ESX server)? AMD CPUs suffer any downgrade on mem bandwidth like Xeons?

Answer (score 2):

The machine has 4 channels, each with 3 slots per processor - for a dual processor config then purely for performance you should go for 24 x 2GB (593907-Bxx) but I'd personally go for the 12 x 4GB so I can easily double my memory without having to throw anything away - it will be slightly slower but no more than ~10%

Comment: there are no plans to upgrade memory on this server

Comment: There rarely is but these things do have a habit of coming along! if you're certain then you have your answer.

Comment: sure that perf hit is only lesser than 10%?